# AJAX results issue - Data.Results is Undefined

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to setup Select2 to use Ajax and am rather stuck. I have debugged in IE and confirmed that my AJAX is returning results, so that doesn't appear to be the issue. The input box loads, but when I type "mi" in for "milk" it just says "searching..." and never finds anything!

Here is my Jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#e1').select2({
                placeholder: "Select an ingredient...",
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                ajax: {
                    url: "../api/IngredientChoices",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    quietMillis: 500,
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term,
                            page_limit: 10,
                            page: page

                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
                        return {
                            results: data.MainName, more:more
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

JSON:

```
[{"SubItemID":1,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"2%","MainName":"Milk"},{"SubItemID":2,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"Skim/Fat Free","MainName":"Milk"},{"SubItemID":3,"MainItemID":2,"SubName":"Chedder","MainName":"Cheese"}]
```

HTML:

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="e1" /></td>
```

If I change the dataType to be just json I get a different kind of error when I type "mi" into the box.

[image]

**Here is the final code for the working version:**

```
            $('#e1').select2({
                placeholder: "Select an ingredient...",
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                ajax: {
                    url: "../api/IngredientChoices",
                    dataType: "json",
                    quietMillis: 500,
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term,
                            page_limit: 10,
                            page: page

                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        var more = (page * 10) < data.length;
                        console.log(more);
                        console.log(data);
                        return { results: data, more: more };

                    },
                    formatResult: function (post) {
                        markup = '<strong>' + post.text + '</strong>';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: jsonp is for outgoing ajax call.../api/IngredientChoices is your local url?then you need data type json only I think

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure of the difference between JSON and JSONP. With JSON i still get the error in the screenshot that I attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are encountering appears to be because of the format of the results you are getting. Select2 is expected results to be a collection of objects with id: and text: attributes.

[{ id: 1, text: 'String' }, { id: 2, text: 'Other String.'}]

Comment: You're correct, I need to change my JSON output to have id and text and it worked. Also, I had to change the results to be data. I've posted my corrected code above for others.

Comment: How was the json field name changed to text??
I had faced similar issue except that I am unable to transform one of my field names('email') to 'text'